A Lifetime movie - Boyfriend framed for domestic violence
I tried to get help from LMN and they do not respond or ignore my question.
This movie was from back in 2000 to 2009, basic plot is a fiancee tries to frame her boyfriend for abuse.
It starts out with a man with dark hair and a beard and he is thinking back now...Dark haired man meets his fiancee, falls in love and they move in together.
Somehow the girl fiancee gets beaten up in the bathrooom with cuts and bruises and her fiance is now "framed" for this abuse. 
Their "lawyer friend" did the beating up (and the lawyer and girl fiancee try to frame HIM for this). The man gets accused.
I cannot recall the name of this movie. Any help would be great!!
